# Where can I get highly technical documentation of Macintosh hardware?

Tags: hardware, design

I am often looking to dig deeper than the overview technical specifications that Apple provides and miss the old Developer Notes that used to be published as Apple Hardware Documentation in HTML and PDF form.

- [2004 ADC - Developer Connection - Hardware Reference Library](http://web.archive.org/web/20040810045409/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Hardware/AppleHardware-date.html)

I can't locate any of these MacBook Pro or [Air](http://web.archive.org/web/20080513043041/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/MacBookAir_0801/index.html) / [Mac Pro](http://web.archive.org/web/20080513043041/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/Mac_Pro_0801/index.html) developer notes [past early 2008 or so in the archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080513043041/http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/HardwareDrivers/idxAppleHardware-date.html). Using a google search as well as searching for developer note is yielding no hits. I can't tell if guides like this are no longer produced or are just hidden behind a pay wall. What programs or resources provide level diagrams and internal hardware design documents short of getting a job with Apple? I'm willing to pay for them, just looking for sources of this information.

I'm not necessarily looking for repair manuals since [iFixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/) does a nice job of documenting tear down disassembly of pretty much anything Apple makes. I'm more interested in the technical discussion about bus speeds, design tradeoffs, and hints on how the machines are built and where the specific limiting factors lie.

For example, being able to read about the storage bus of the MacBook Air lets me know if I can replace the flash storage and not guess whether it's on a SATA bus or uses a proprietary controller in addition to a proprietary shape / connector.

Comment: Kidnap Jonathan Ive?

Comment: You used to be able to apply as an Apple authorized service provider and have access to repair parts and manuals, but new applications to that program is currently suspended in the US. http://www.apple.com/support/programs/aasp/

Answer (score 2):

As far as repair of hardware http://ifixit.com is actually pretty awesome, more visual than you may be looking for however.

Comment: I'm not looking to repair things - I want detailed technical block level diagrams explaining the components, bus speeds. I'll edit the question to make this clearer - thanks for the advice - they are visually awesome even though they aren't filled with the wisdom of the maker like the official repair guides linked from GSX :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

[Global Service Exchange](http://gsx.apple.com/) might be what you're looking for - its the worldwide system that provides repair manuals, software, and case histories for all Apple products.  You might also want to review [this Apple page](http://www.apple.com/support/programs/ssa/).

If you're a [JAMF Casper site](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/solutions/) and have a GSX account, you can automatically import and track Mac warranty information, which is really useful for larger installations.

Comment: I'll check with JAMF - but the current Apple programs for getting into GSX require a company with 50+ apple products, an Account Executive to refer them. The service program for individuals is suspended so that would have been a no-brainer without all the enterprise restrictions.