# Macbook Air motherboard description

Tags: macbook-pro, motherboard

Where can I find something like description, specs, details etc for MacBook Air 11's motherboard (logic board)? I need full information about all parts of motherboard. I tried to google it, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of specs are you looking for?

Comment: Major chips. Lan, VGA, bluetooth, USB, wireless etc - as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFixit has nice [teardowns](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-Models-A1237-and-A1304-Teardown/598/1), with chip references. No specs about the chips themselves though.

Answer (score 2):

We have a general question on the site asking for similar details:

[Where can I get highly technical documentation of Macintosh hardware?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44696/where-can-i-get-highly-technical-documentation-of-macintosh-hardware)

If you need better information than what is available for free on the internet, you can pay for access to Apple's internal [Global Service Exchange](http://gsx.apple.com) web site that has extraordinarily detailed information on the entire line of Apple products.

Comment: GSX will not give you this information either. (I have access to GSX.) You will get limited information in the device's TechNote if one is available for that model. (You need to have service personnel status with Apple to access this information.)

Comment: Thanks - I don't have access these days - seems the detail from years past isn't shared anymore. :-( I recall fondly the system diagrams for the Power Mac and early Mac Pro - those we're the days.